# Why is ondrop not working?

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get drag and drop working, but I am wiring a function to the 'ondrop' event, but the function is never called.

Here is a Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/qGEdYO8okRZAR3bnZrNk?p=preview

This is the trivial wiring example:

```
<script>
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');

holder.ondragenter = function (e) { 
    this.className = 'nicenice lvl-over'; 
    return false; 
};
holder.ondragleave = function () { 
    this.className = 'nicenice'; 
    return false; 
};
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("GOT DROP EVENT");
    alert("dropped here");
};
</script>
```

I put the alert in there just to see if I can get some indication of getting the drop event.  I added the ondragenter and ondragleave mainly just to see if I was getting ANY event.  Those events I seem to get.  What have I omitted that is necessary to receive a drop event?  what other MAGIC is needed?

My goal is to hook this up with AngularJS, but I needed to simplify in order to ask the question here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is the only magic left:

```
holder.ondragover = function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault() 
}
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mW3NR0QBuPI59sDEDRo?p=preview)

Comment: "ondragover"  how strange.  Thanks, I am getting the event.     By the way, you set a "draggable" attribute on the p tag, however, I don't seem to be able to actually drag that thing that says "Drag me!"   Should I be able to drag it?  Seems like I should.  I **can** drag it it in Chrome.  I can't drag it in Mozilla.  Non-standard?

Comment: @AgilePro Oh interesting, I actually took it from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp though I'm trying to get into the habit of checking the mdn first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable . Looks like "draggable" is still experimental.

Comment: still having this issue in 2019, very odd. thank you!

Comment: this is still an issue and in chrome I still get no event fired on exit.. @AgilePro in firefox you must set the `event.dataTransfer.setData` method.

Comment: Thanks this saves my day